# How to pass a string as a macro?

Tags: c

There are many functions in the C libraries that require users to input with macros.
I wonder, if I have an array of strings, with contents of macros, like so:

```
char s[][3] = {"SIGINT", "SIGKILL", "SIGSTOP"};
```

How can I pass these strings as macros? (Like so:)

```
signal(s[0], do_something);
```

with `do_something` is a function pointer.

(and yes, technically I can pass ints in this case, but... hypothetically, ya know?)

EDIT:
As @RemyLebeau and SGeorgiades point out, the "SIGINT",... are aliases for integer consts, and therefore can be stored in an int array, like so:

```
int s[3] = {SIGINT, SIGKILL, SIGSTOP};
```

Comment: The 1st parameter of `signal()` is an `int`, not a `char*` string. There is no way to convert a `char*` string into an `int` the way you are trying to. You will have to  create a lookup at runtime to translate the `char*` strings into corresponding `int` values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed, but you can also pass macros like SIGINT.

Comment: SIGINT is not a macro, it is just an alias for the appropriate integer constant.

Comment: Perhaps what you want instead is `int s[3] = {SIGINT, SIGKILL, SIGSTOP};`

Comment: @SGeorgiades indeed :) thanks for your help! Should you like to add an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you want instead is:

```
int s[3] = { SIGINT, SIGKILL, SIGSTOP };

signal(s[0], do_something);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although SGeorgiades and Remy Lebeau already gave you the answer, here is something that I've used in the past to allow conversion and pretty printing of signal numbers and names:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sigfun {
    int signo;
    const char *signame;
};

#define SIGFUN(_sig) \
    { \
        .signo = _sig, \
        .signame = #_sig \
    }

struct sigfun siglist[] = {
    SIGFUN(SIGINT),
    SIGFUN(SIGKILL),
    SIGFUN(SIGSTOP),
    // ...
    { .signo = 0, .signame = NULL }
};

#define SIGFORALL(_sig) \
    _sig = siglist;  _sig->signame != NULL;  ++_sig

int
signame_to_signo(const char *signame)
{
    struct sigfun *sig;

    for (SIGFORALL(sig)) {
        if (strcmp(sig->signame,signame) == 0)
            break;
    }

    return sig->signo;
}

const char *
signo_to_signame(int signo)
{
    struct sigfun *sig;

    for (SIGFORALL(sig)) {
        if (signo == sig->signo)
            break;
    }

    return sig->signame;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> why not put `for` into `SIGFORALL`? –
> tstanisl

For a few reasons ...

I've done that before (e.g.):

```
#define SIGFORALL(_sig) \
    for (_sig = siglist;  _sig->signame != 0;  ++_sig)

SIGFORALL(sig) {
    // do stuff
}
```

1. This tends to confuse certain IDEs and/or tools that parse the code *without* running it through the preprocessor.
2. It's also more difficult for programmers to quickly (without digesting the macro) skip over it.
3. They don't see a `for` and have trouble figuring out what `SIGFORALL(sig) {` does.
4. Is the macro a wrapper for `if`, `for`, or `while`?

With:

```
#define SIGFORALL(_sig) \
    _sig = siglist;  _sig->signame != 0;  ++_sig

for (SIGFORALL(sig)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

there is a better chance they can continue around the construct because they can understand (i.e. skip over) the `for (...)` [syntactically] without having to know what the macro is doing. That is, nobody has to "drill down" into the macro unless they wish to.

Another reason is that *without* the `for` in the macro, we can add extra code to the `for` loop's initialization and iteration expressions. It's more flexible.

For example, I've used a similar macro for linked list traversal and wanted to know the index/count of an element:

```
#define LLFORALL(_node) \
    _node = nodelist;  _node != NULL;  _node = _node->next

int idx;
for (idx = 0, LLFORALL(node), ++idx) {
    if (node->value == 5)
        printf("found value at index %d\n",idx);
}
```

There's *no* absolute rule about this. Ultimately, it's a [personal] style preference.

Comment: why not put `for` into `SIGFORALL`?

Comment: @tstanisl I've updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: interesting, why not `FOR_ALL_SIG`? there is an explicit `FOR` in the beginning.

Comment: @tstanisl Using `FORALLSIG` (vs. `FOR_ALL_SIG`) _is_ [just] personal style preference. I've been doing the former for decades [I have a _lot_ of code that uses that style], so I "think" like that. I _am_ a big fan of "snake case", so I do that too (e.g.) `FORALLSIG_FWD` and `FORALLSIG_REV`. Sometimes, it just is the "muse of the day"